# MVC and RedirectToAction Alternative

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirecttoaction

We are building an app using MVC 5.  Basically, we have a View Index with several radio buttons and a Submit button.  Some radio buttons have a dropdown with selection options. Currently, our HomeController has a big Switch statement and I am sure there is a more elegant way to load a page based on selection.

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Submit(SpecificationQuery input)
 {
     switch (input.specifications)
     {
         case "updateChannel":
             return RedirectToAction("AddUpdateDelete", "Channel");
         case "etc":
             return RedirectToAction("Etc", "Channel");
         default:
             return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
      }
  }
```

I can't change the page of radio buttons but it seems there must be a much better way to do this.  I've been researching MapRoutes thinking maybe the name of the radio button might be added to it somehow but am afraid I am misguided.  Any suggestions?

Comment: look into custom routing.

Comment: Yep. This is entirely about your routes. Unless you can come up with some sort of generic route that can be passed the input value explicitly, then you have no choice but to use a switch statement.

Comment: Would it make sense to create a couple of custom properties for the radio buttons that stores the Controller and View to be returned when Submit button is clicked?